# Task vs Reduce CPU Usage

Tags: c#, wpf

Forgive me if I ask a stupid question.I'm working on Task.I have a code as below:

```
private string result;
public string Result
{
      get { return result; }
      set
      {
        if (value != result)
        {
           result = value;
           OnRaise("Result");
        }
      }
}
```

ICommand:

```
private ICommand _cmd;
public ICommand Cmd
{
      get
      {
         _cmd = _cmd ?? new RelayCommand(s => RunAction(), () => IsEnable);
         return _cmd;
      }
}
```

method and task:

```
int count = 0;
private async void RunAcion()
{
    IsEnable = false;
    var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();           
    await Task.Run(() => Runcmd()).ContinueWith(s => this.Result =   count.ToString(), context);
    IsEnable = true;           
}
void Runcmd()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    count++;
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" 
    Height="50" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnable}"
    Command="{Binding Cmd, Delay=1000}"
/>
<TextBlock Foreground="#4C4C4C" Text="{Binding Show}"/>
```

Getting 50% CPU when running.How to reduce CPU usage?

Comment: You shouldnt call Thread.Sleep in a Task environment, you should use Task.Delay(2000). You shouldn't use `async void` unless they're events, you should use `async Task`. `Runcmd` can be `async Task` which will remove the need for `Task.Run` and `ContinueWith`

Comment: I found this little gem, may help you out a bunch with WPF async commands: http://jake.ginnivan.net/awaitable-delegatecommand/

Comment: @CallumLinington, nothing wrong with `Thread.Sleep` to simulate synchronous operation, nothing bad with making event handler (they are `void`) `async` either, not sure why your comment is upvoted. To OP - the problem could be with how you invoke `Result`. Try to do it in classic way, `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Result = whatever);` after task if finished or simply set the value after `await` line instead of using `ContinueWith` and `context`.

Comment: App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke give 40%.How to get better? How to get better@Sinatr

Comment: async Task get 30% and 40 can't get better@CallumLinington

Comment: When remove async and await I'm getting this warning: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.@CallumLinington

Comment: finally  I found out the issue is CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); in RelayCommand .Now getting better.cpu usage is 0.5%.Awsome!@CallumLinington